# Disappearing characters between youtube-dl, ffmpeg, and cmd

Tags: windows, command-line, ffmpeg, cmd.exe

so what happens is that if the video title has a symbol that isn't supported by your current locale then ffmpeg won't be able to get to that file properly.

Here's one example

```
►2 HOURS BEST MELODIC DUBSTEP MIX APRIL 2013◄ ヽ( ≧ω≦)ﾉ
```

as you may or may not be able to see, lots of symbols from unicode.

The problem is that in cmd and ffmpeg, though cmd can see

```
►2 HOURS BEST MELODIC DUBSTEP MIX APRIL 2013◄ ヽ( ≧ω≦)ﾉ
```

ffmpeg only sees

```
2 HOURS DUBSTEP_DRUMSTEP MIX AUGUST 2013 ヽ(≧ω≦)ﾉ
```

This is the exact error message (i'm using youtube-dl)

```
[ffmpeg] Adding metadata to 'C:\Music\ToBeDone\2014-06-01\►2 HOURS DUBSTEP_DRUMSTEP MIX AUGUST 2013◄ ヽ( ≧ω≦)ﾉ.mp4'
ERROR: C:\Music\ToBeDone\2014-06-01\2 HOURS DUBSTEP_DRUMSTEP MIX AUGUST 2013 ヽ(≧ω≦)ﾉ.mp4: No such file or directory
ERROR: WARNING: unable to obtain file audio codec with ffprobe
```

After some research i've determined that by changing the system locale you can change which symbols cmd can support.

However

```
ヽ
```

Used to appear as a box in a question mark in United states locale. In japanese locale it appears as it does on your screen right now.

the problem with

```
◄
```

is that even though it's not appearing as a question mark in a box (it's appearing as how it should be), ffmpeg (or cmd) can't detect it properly.

(Refer back to the error message, i'll repost it below.)

```
[ffmpeg] Adding metadata to 'C:\Music\ToBeDone\2014-06-01\►2 HOURS DUBSTEP_DRUMSTEP MIX AUGUST 2013◄ ヽ( ≧ω≦)ﾉ.mp4'
ERROR: C:\Music\ToBeDone\2014-06-01\2 HOURS DUBSTEP_DRUMSTEP MIX AUGUST 2013 ヽ(≧ω≦)ﾉ.mp4: No such file or directory
ERROR: WARNING: unable to obtain file audio codec with ffprobe
```

So as you can see, I think cmd passed on the symbol correctly to ffmpeg seeing from the adding metadata line, but when it actually does the operation ffmpeg loses

```
► and ◄
```

Could this be a bug with ffmpeg? MY workaround so far with incompatible symbols was to change the system locale, but I don't think i can do that with these two symbols...

These are the unique characters that i need to have a locale that supports

```
Ö

◄ ヽ( ≧ω≦)ﾉ

( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)

(_≧∇≦)

†

【
```

More info on the problem in general

```
https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/issues/2999
```

and this is what's going on (Batch Script)

```
@echo off
setlocal
cd C:\youtube-dl

set /p "var1=Enter URL: " %=% pause
if defined var1 set "var1=%var1:"=%"
set "var2=%date:/=-%" 
set "var3=%%(title)s.%%(ext)s"
youtube-dl "%var1%" -ci -o "C:\Music\ToBeDone\%var2%\%var3%" -f best -x --no-mtime --  add-metadata 
youtube-dl "%var1%" --skip-download -ci -o "C:\Music\ToBeDone\%var2%\Thumbnail\%var3%" --write-thumbnail
youtube-dl "%var1%" --skip-download -ci -o   "C:\Music\ToBeDone\%var2%\Description\%var3%" --write-description
```